# Making Button be assigned to make only one random label visible

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, random, label

I have created an array of labels to be visible with a buttons click but yet since I have many buttons I want to assign a button to make only one label visible 
I am having trouble with making a button making more than one label visible

This is the code I used :

```
var labels = Controls.OfType<Label>().ToArray();
//And then randomly make on of them visible.
var random = new Random();
var label = labels[random.Next(0, labels.Count - 1)];
label.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Can you please tell us is it in WINFORMS , WPF or ASP.NET?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Looking at your previous question which is also down voted, please have a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Okay I have made some adjustments

Answer (score 0):

In Winforms you can simply declare a private `Random` variable, and then in the `Click` event of one of your buttons, you can choose a random number that's within the valid index range of the label array, something like:

```
private Label[] labels = new Label[10];  // Presumably this array is filled somewhere
private Random rnd = new Random();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < labels.Length; i++)
    {
        labels[i] = new Label
        {
            Height = 20,
            Left = 10,
            Name = $"Label{i}",
            Tag = i,
            Text = $"Label{i}",
            Top = 10 + 20 * i,
            Visible = false
        };

        this.Controls.Add(labels[i]);
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (labels != null && labels.Length > 0)
    {
        // If needed, this will hide any currently visible labels in the array
        foreach(var label in labels.Where(label => label != null && label.Visible))
        {
            label.Visible = false;
        }

        // Pick a random label and make it visible
        labels[rnd.Next(0, labels.Length)].Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the code brings out a Null reference  exception error, any help

Comment: Yeah but it's still showing the error message when I click the button

Comment: Did you see the comment, `\\ Presumably this array is filled somewhere`? You said you created an array of labels, so just replace `labels` with the name of the array that you populated.

Comment: I updated the sample to include code that populates the label array in the `Form_Load` event.